# Sc_inout<bool> Not changing value

Tags: signals, fifo, systemc

I'm trying to debug a larger program I wrote and I extracted one of the threads which basically is writing a array of 24 values to a fifo and the other end is another thread which is supposed to read the data only after all of it has been written.

Transmit.h

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
SC_MODULE(Transmit){
    sc_inout <bool> ServerTx;
    sc_fifo_out<int> PacketTx;

    void Tx();

    SC_CTOR(Transmit){
        sc_fifo<int> PacketTx(24);
        SC_THREAD(Tx){}
    }
};
```

Transmit.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Transmit.h"

void Transmit::Tx(){
    int imageInfo[24] = { 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 200, 600, 400, 800, 2, 400, 200, 600, 400, 3, 600, 400, 800, 600, 4, 800, 600, 1000, 800 };
    while (1){
        if (ServerTx == 0){
            cout << "ServerTx Before Write: " << ServerTx << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++){
                cout << "Transmit Value: " << imageInfo[i] << endl;
                PacketTx.write(imageInfo[i]);
            }
            ServerTx = 1;
            cout << "ServerTx After Write: " << ServerTx << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Done Transmitting Packet." << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Transmit.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    sc_signal <bool> ServerTx;
    sc_fifo<int> Packet(24);

    Transmit t1("Transmit");
    t1.PacketTx(Packet);
    t1.ServerTx(ServerTx);

    ServerTx = 0;
    sc_start();
    return 0;
}
```

What im seeing is that regardless of the type i declare my signal `ServerTx`, **it never update its value**. I dont know if there is some delay in systemC with updating signal values or not, but I have no idea what to do from here. Im extending this simple handshaking into a larger program I wrote and if this doesnt work then I might have to go scrap the entire thing.

Here's a debug printout of what im seeing. I expected `ServerTx` to equal 1 since i just set its value but it stays 0. No idea what is happening or if im misunderstanding something in SystemC.

[image]

**Update:**

Adding `wait(SC_ZERO_TIME);` after the while loop worked in changing the value of `ServerTx`, but now when i add in my Receive code it I get the following error:

[image]

Here's my Receive code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Receive.h"

    void Receive::Rx(){
        while (1){
            if (ServerTx == 1){
                cout << "ServerTx before Read: " << ServerTx << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++){
                    imageInfo[i] = PacketRx.read();
                    cout << "Receive Value: " << imageInfo[i] << endl;
                }
                ServerTx = 0; //Done reading server packet data
                cout << "ServerTx after Read: " << ServerTx << endl;
            }
            else{
                wait(10, SC_NS);
            }
            wait(SC_ZERO_TIME);
        }
    }
```

and I changed Main.cpp to the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Receive.h"
#include "Transmit.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    sc_signal <bool> ServerTx;
    sc_fifo<int> Packet(24);

    Receive r1("Receive");
    r1.PacketRx(Packet);
    r1.ServerTx(ServerTx);

    Transmit t1("Transmit");
    t1.PacketTx(Packet);
    t1.ServerTx(ServerTx);

    ServerTx = 0;
    sc_start();


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Transmit::Tx` thread you are not allowing the control back to the SystemC kernel.

SystemC is a co-operative multi-tasking simulation environment. Which means you need to periodically synchronize the state of the simulation with the SystemC kernel.

Try out this modification in Transmit.cpp for adding a delta delay in your simulation:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Transmit.h"

void Transmit::Tx(){
  int imageInfo[24] = { 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 200, 600, 400, 800, 2, 400, 200, 600, 400, 3, 600, 400, 800, 600, 4, 800, 600, 1000, 800 };
  while (1){
    if (ServerTx == 0){
      cout << "ServerTx Before Write: " << ServerTx << endl;
      for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++){
          cout << "Transmit Value: " << imageInfo[i] << endl;
          PacketTx.write(imageInfo[i]);
      }
      ServerTx = 1;
      cout << "ServerTx After Write: " << ServerTx << endl;
    }
    else{
      cout << "Done Transmitting Packet." << endl;
    }
    wait(SC_ZERO_TIME); //< Delta Delay
  }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. For better understanding the SystemC standard you can refer to the [SystemC LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1666/download/1666-2011.pdf).
2. If you have access to the hard-copy of the SystemC from Ground Up(2nd Edition).

Refer: *Chapter 2 section 2.4 page: 29* about the SystemC simulation kernel. (or have a look at google books snapshot [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Op2a6yiO9jwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=systemc%20from%20ground%20up&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFq6GMqK3TAhWKr1QKHYGFC_QQ6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=systemc%20from%20ground%20up&f=false)).

Comment: This worked. However, once i included the Receive portion of my code, i get another error "**Unhandled exception at 0x7777A932 in ConsoleApplication3.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: sc_core::sc_report at memory location 0x0161F324.**" My receive code is basically the same as my Transmit code except im checking if `ServerTx==1` and if so, I read the fifo data into an array. Once im done reading fifo data, i clear `ServerTx` so `ServerTx = 0;`. Inside the else statements i added a 5 ns wait. Any ideas what's going on? I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Your threads are free-running threads, which by default are not sensitive to any SystemC events, you at least need one wait statement in your SC_THREAD's. If you could elaborate on the scenario, or point to an earlier question that would make it easier to identify the scenario you are trying to model using SystemC.

Comment: I did include waits in my threads though. See my updated question for what im trying to do.

Comment: The basic concept im trying to model is the interaction between a Server module and 3 Mobile modules. Server sents a packet of data to each mobile, which in turn is processed and sent back. Only one module can read or write on the "network" which I wanted to use sc_inout as a flag to show if the network is busy or not. My core code functionality is there, but i cannot get the systemc portions to work such as these threads. Likewise, i need to use threads since i need to halt execution and retry reading/writing on the network if it is already being used.

Comment: If you are trying to model a software/logical network simulation then SystemC is not suitable for running that kind of simulation, as you would be implementing a lot of logic for the router module and other supporting modules.

Comment: If you are trying to drive multiple values into the sc_inout port interface across multiple modules you will soon hit the multiple driver issue. You will have to use the sc_resolved type in that scenario.

Comment: Its not as complex of network as you think it is. Its very basic. just packet data transfer and processing. I dont need to actually model routers or anything. just a very simple data transfer/receive. As far as the multiple drivers issue, im using some variables to avoid this, for example. The threads which read/write from the fifo are set to wait for different times. This way, if someone is reading or writing, nobody else can. Likewise, im using another set of flags to determine who should be reading or writing. I just need to figure out why i cant run those two threads above at the same time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142002/discussion-between-ameyavs-and-javia1492).